# How to get the node's parent based on the successor in BST?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

In BST, if each node does not have a pointer to its parent, instead, have a pointer to its successor (also has left and right child pointer). How could we design an algorithm to get its parent based on the successor pointer?

Comment: Can you provide a simple diagram? I don't understand the difference between successor and parent.

Comment: @Randall Cook the successor of node x is the smallest key greater than x.key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a node `n`, we can repeatedly get the successor `s` until we get one that `s.left == n`. `s` is then the parent. If no such node is found, `n` is a right child and we repeatedly get the successor `s`, starting from the first element (easy to get by repeatedly calling `e = e.left`) until we get `s.right == n`, then `s` is the parent.